# Is there any example on how to toggle AVNET Zynq 7000 User LED using DMA in Linux?

Tags: embedded-linux, dma

I am looking for an example on how to write on to GPIO i.e. user LED gpio using DMA in linux. How can I do so? Is there any example that illustrates this. I am using Zynq7000 SOC and my board is AVNET Microzed.

Comment: *"user LED gpio using DMA"* -- (1) *"LED gpio"* is actually an oxymoron.  Either create an LED device (that just happens to be controlled by GPIO), or access a GPIO pin (that happens to be connected to the LED).  The former is prefered method.  (2) Why DMA?  What makes you think that there's a data transfer that requires DMA?

Comment: @sawdust, there are LED strips that require some kind of custom serial bit banging which is time specific, but I don't think this is the case here.